# Android overlap other apps permission

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions

I'm having a problem, my app is closing when other apps are open, so i think that's a overlap problem, so i want to make my app overlap the others when he's open

I use cordova to make the app

Comment: There's no such thing as "overlapping" other apps - apps are entirely sandboxed so cannot interact with each other except via explicit mechanisms (e.g. Android Intents). If your app is closing it's probably because it's crashing - check the logcat output for details of the crash.

Comment: Ok i saw something similar to this, "overlap other apps" that is something you can deactivate, but i'll check the logcat output thx <3